Drivers for Intel NUC5CPYH Mini PC are not available
I need the audio driver for Intel NUC5CPYH Mini PC and I can't find that on the Intel's website. Why the drivers are gone and how do I download them
Here is the link to the driver page.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/85254/intel-nuc-kit-nuc5cpyh/downloads.html
Is it going to work if I install driver of any other NUC PC?

Is the driver for the same audio device? If so then it should work. You haven’t given us enough information to determine what you’re asking. The driver you linked to isn’t for an audio device.

No, the audio driver is missing on that page. Where to get it?

You haven’t given us enough information to determine what you’re asking. The driver you linked to isn’t for an audio device. Once you [edit] your question with enough information to answer your question an answer can be submitted.
